# Circular references in Spring due to Profile based injection

Tags: java, spring

I have an account and database interfaces.

1. Database is an i/f It has two impls. 
   Cloud(to be used in prod) 
   RAM(To be used in test)
2. Account is an i/f. It has one impl right now. SavingAccount.
   Any Account impl needs a db.

SavingsAccount class comes autowired with Database instance.

There are two java-configs files (one for prod, one for test) that aid in injecting right instances of classes based on profile. Both extend a common class to avoid code duplication.

**Issue**
Depending on profile being initialized with, I want the SavingsAccount to pick the right db instance for that profile. But, running the binary is leading into circular references in spring. I get error like

```
Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

My spring configuration is in this [Github link](https://github.com/seshumadhav/java-projects/tree/master/spring-profiles/src/com/spring/profiles)

I understand why there is a circular ref - ProfileDemo wants db > db wants ProdConfiguration > ProdConfiguration wants CommonConfiguration > CommonConfiguration wants SavingsAccount > SavingsAccount wants db.

I am unable to wire them smoothly yet retain the design. I do not want to duplicate code for injecting SavingsAccount in every configuration file. Some other questions on SO really didnt help. I would like to configure in a manner that I can avoid circular dependency, without having to duplicate code and retain design. Any help is appreciated.

**Exception trace**

```
Nov 29, 2013 4:36:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Nov 29, 2013 4:36:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@1abfb235: startup date [Fri Nov 29 16:36:38 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 29, 2013 4:36:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7ad698f7: defining beans [profileDemo,cloud,RAM,savingsAccount,prodConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,getTheDb,getTestDb,getProdDb,account]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 29, 2013 4:36:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7ad698f7: defining beans [profileDemo,cloud,RAM,savingsAccount,prodConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,getTheDb,getTestDb,getProdDb,account]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'profileDemo': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.ProfileDemo.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prodConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount com.spring.profiles.CommonConfiguration.savingsAccount; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'savingsAccount': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at com.spring.profiles.ProfileDemo.main(ProfileDemo.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.ProfileDemo.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prodConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount com.spring.profiles.CommonConfiguration.savingsAccount; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'savingsAccount': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prodConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount com.spring.profiles.CommonConfiguration.savingsAccount; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'savingsAccount': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount com.spring.profiles.CommonConfiguration.savingsAccount; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'savingsAccount': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'savingsAccount': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.profiles.Database com.spring.profiles.SavingsAccount.db; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTheDb': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of profiles to have either one bean or the other. Currently you always have the same bean and try to select one based on profile. Next to that you are also injecting the bean in the configuration which requires that bean.

In short (and IMHO) you are making things to complex.

1. Remove the autowiring of the service from your @Configuration class.
2. Change your profile based configuration classes NOT to extend the COmmonConfiguration and in both of them create the same method returning the same bean. (Let say name it `database`).
3. Inject `database` in your service or simply remve the qualifiers all together and simply inject based on type (which is possible now because you only have a single instance of your `database` bean).

-

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public CommonConfiguration() {}
```

Modify your Prod and Test configurations (and remove `@Component` from the DB classes to prevent duplication, due to component-scanning);

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestConfiguration  {

    @Bean
    public Database database() {
        return new TestDb();
    }
}
```

Production confgig.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdConfiguration  {

    @Bean
    public Database database() {
        return new ProdDb();
    }
}
```

Modify your `SavingsAccount` by removing the `@Qualifier`

```
@Component
public class SavingsAccount implements Account {

  @Autowired
  private Database db;

  @Override
  public void deposit(int money) {
    System.out.println("\n\nSomeModule starts working");
    db.save(money);
  }

}
```

Of course you finally have to modify your `ProfileDemo` class as there will only be 1 database available. Also due to the `@ComponentScan` on the configuration class you can remove the spring.xml file.

```
@Component
public class ProfileDemo {

  @Autowired
  private Database db;

  @Autowired
  private Account  account;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext contxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.getEnvironment().addActiveProfile("prod");
    context.register(CommonConfiguration.class);
    context.refresh();

    ProfileDemo demo = context.getBean(ProfileDemo.class);

    // Test autowiring of databases based on profile
    demo.db.save(10);
    demo.account.deposit(40);
    context.close();
  }

}
```

This way all selection is done by spring. No need to inject everything (imagine next to test and prod something like UAT, performance tst, etc. multipl environments. Things would get nasty pretty quickly. Not to mention your `CommonConfiguration` isn't all to common any more that way.

Comment: @m-deinum I liked your design much better than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your @Qualifier values should be the same, no matter which environment you are using.

Create a separate @Configuration file for each database, each with @Profile("something"). Put the database-related beans in each of those.

By using @ActiveProfiles, you are then defining which configuration will be active. That ensures that only one database will be linked up to the application.